# Finished off the night "with a rubber"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Reading the diary of a doctor in Canada, 1845-46, often refers to "having a rubber" at the end of the day which seems like a nightcap. Does anyone know why the word rubber is used?

Comment: Sure it wasn't a card game? "rubber of bridge"

Comment: Doesn't rubber mean condom?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան ["The first rubber condom was produced in 1855"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_condoms)

Comment: There used to be some amusing misunderstandings back when *rubber* was AmE for condom but BrE for pencil eraser. But *rubber* for condom has all but disappeared from AmE by now. So has *French letter,* also at the cost of a good joke involving a supposed academic department of such.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: "Rubber for condom has all but disappeared from AmE by now."  Sorry, I think that is an exaggeration.  Do you have some support for the claim?  I don't have proof to the contrary, but there is [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use+a+rubber%2Cuse+a+condom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20a%20rubber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20a%20condom%3B%2Cc0), at least.

Comment: @Drew I confess I was drawing only on personal experience. I haven't heard the usage in years, literally. In your NGram the lines seem to cross at about 1982, a grimly significant date. (Substituting the verb "wear" moves the date about two years earlier.)

Comment: @Brian I have heard _rubber_ used to mean a condom quite recently—by a teenager, no less—so I agree with Drew that it's still alive and kicking.

Answer (score 21):

Given the date my money would be on its referring to a *[rubber](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rubber)* of [whist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whist), though bridge, cribbage, even backgammon are mentioned in the usage examples for this sense in the OED. It means an odd-numbered series of games, of which the winner of the majority of individual games is the overall winner.

Comment: And allegedly "rubber" in this sense is originally [from the game of bowls](http://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/brewers/rubber-whist.html) (where the balls rub against each other)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Not to contradict your bowls information, though in relation to the OP's question it should be noted that the Canadian doctor's rubbers apparently took place at the end of the day. This makes it fairly unlikely that he was playing bowls (which is an outdoor game), unless it was the height of the Canadian summer (when the evenings would be light until something like 10.30 or 11 p.m., depending on how far north he was).

Comment: @ErikKowal er, I certainly did not claim the good doctor was actually playing bowls before bed! My comment was about the etymology of this phrase.

Comment: Too long ago for bridge. Almost certainly whist.

Comment: @MartinSmith - No, I get that. I hoped I had phrased my comment in such a way as to make it clear that I did not take your comment to suggest that the doctor was actually playing bowls, but apparently I did not succeed in getting this across.

Comment: @Erik Oh I see, in that case we are in agreement then!

Comment: Just found one diary entry in which the doctor states "Played a rubber in the evening".